# How to re-enable syntax highlighting in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

**Vim language highlighting has quit working only for one specific file.**

I've been using Vim in WSL (Ubuntu) for several months now without problems. My PC is Windows 10 Professional. Strangely, Vim is no longer highlighting properly when I open a particular file. Everything works fine with every other file, but if I open this one file, it does not display correctly. The language highlighting is gone. Line numbers, tabs, and end-of-file-tildes still follow the color scheme, but my actual code is simply colored white. Does anyone know how to fix this?

More details:

- The file type is *.v
- If I rename the file, it displays correctly.
- If multiple files are open at once (i.e. split view), every other file displays fine while this one file does not.
- The problem arose in the middle of a work session, and I changed nothing in the vimrc before the problem arose.
- After seeing the problem, I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, followed by a restart.
- I tried changing the color scheme in my vimrc.

Nothing I tried worked. Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: This question will be moved to vim.stackexchange.com

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate for vim.stackexchange.com

Comment: Good point. I'll move the question to that site. Thanks.

Comment: See the solution here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26614/30722

Answer (score 0):

I have one mapping to toggle syntax, maybe it will help you

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <Leader>s exists('g:syntax_on') ? ':syntax off<cr>' : ':syntax enable<cr>'
```